# How to replace stuff between two flag symbols using regex

Tags: regex, pcre

For example I have below text

> some {}} outside, and some inside $aa{bb}cc{{dd}ee}ff$, and some more $aa{bb}cc{{dd}ee}ff$ here.

I call `$` flag symbol, and now I want to replace all `{` or `}` between pairs of `$...$` using regex.

The only way I can think of is to replace multiple times, using regex

```
(\$.*?)(\{|\})
```

each time it replaces a `{` or `}` inside `$...$`. After enough time of replacement, we got

> some {}} outside, and some inside $aabbccddeeff$, and some more
>   $aabbccddeeff$ here.

The drawback is that you don't know how many times it needs to get `{` or `}` completely replaced, and it apparently not efficient at all.

So I am wondering, is regex capable to doing this in a single run? For regex flavor I mean perl compatible. But if perl can not do this, I would love to know if other regex flavor can do.

Comment: What language are you implementing this in? Can you post an example expected output for your input there?

Comment: Hi ,@CertainPerformance I updated my post

Comment: regexes don't by the themselves support **any** kind of replacement, modification, etc -- matching is the only thing they do. So you need more tags for whatever tool or layer you're adding that supports making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
[{}](?=[^$]*\$(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkgjPn/1)**

Replace each match with a blank string.

**Explanation:**

- `[{}]` - matches either `{` or `}`
- `(?=[^$]*\$(?:(?:[^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)` - positive lookahead to make sure that the above match is followed by odd number of `$` somewhere later in the string. This would make sure that `{` or `}` is followed by 1 or 3 or 5 or 7... instances of `$` somewhere later in the string.

Comment: Definitely not generic to all regex variants. Has the OP indicated that they have PCRE extensions available? Much of this (`(?:...)`) doesn't work even in POSIX ERE, much less BRE; and even some modern engines intentionally don't support lookahead/lookbehind (since those features have serious impact on worst-case performance).

Comment: OP has mentioned that Perl compatible regex is required.

Comment: So they have; adding that to the question's tagging.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your trick is so clever. There remains one thing I am not sure. Why we have to use non capture group? I found simply use capture group like `[{}](?=[^$]*\$(([^$]*\$){2})*[^$]*$)` also give the same result. But the highlight is somewhat different on regex101.com. See https://regex101.com/r/nkgjPn/2

Comment: Yes you can remove the non-capturing group. In that case, whatever is matched by the regex pattern inside the parenthesis, will be captured in a Group. Refer [THIS](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to know more about Regex Groups.